# Typescript inferrence not resolving correctly for nested generic types

Tags: typescript

I have some Typescript that's not being inferred the way I'm expecting. I mocked up some sudo code here that duplicates the problem:

```js
  //////////
  // Types
  /////////

  type RegExpForString<T> = T extends string ? RegExp | T : T;

  // Allow all values of type string in T to also allow regex 
  type Schema<T> = { 
    [P in keyof T]?: RegExpForString<T[P]>;
  }

  /////////
  // Usage
  /////////

  // Accept only Types that have a property called "prop" that has a value type of string
  function test<T extends { prop: string }>() {

    const x: T["prop"] = "string"; // No Error (working as Expected) 
        

    const y: T["prop"] = 0; // Error (working as Expected)
      // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T["prop"]'.
        // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.


    let mow: Schema<T> = {};
    mow.prop = 'test'; // Error (This one is the unexpected one I think should be working)
      // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RegExpForString<T["prop"]>'.
  }
```

So the above is simplified (the actual code has these Types a bit more nested and additional unions) but represent the error I'm getting.

So my understanding of the above is:

- Within the function `T`  is guaranteed to have a key `prop` with a string value (because of the `extend`)
- `T['prop']`'s type can be inferred at this point to be identical to `string` (we see this working on const `x` and `y` the function)
- When I define `mow` it is allowed to have a key `prop` (may also be `undefined`) with a value type of `RegExpForString<T['prop']>` (since we know T has a key `prop`)
- `RegExpForString<T['prop']>` <==> `RegExpForString<string>` <==> `RegExp | string` so `mow.prop` should be able to be set to a string or regex expression.

I think I'm understanding this correctly and am thinking that maybe there is a limitation of typescript's ability to infer nested types (I tried looking this up but couldn't find anything). Also possible that I'm misreading/misunderstanding something (still learning Typescript) and if someone would be able to correct me that'd be great.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATD04yCgXYBUCeAHApgZxmS0sBcVVgAlVAcwFEAPZAMQHsAnAZT0YEsA7MgHngD5gAXgTBUVPKk4ATdMHRsuZYAH4S5asmAAfUQC4EAbihY48RgENO6AGZMAtsAvACaAORyAbhYA2AVwwXeicfH2A-dCIAdUtkNEZ8QmBmAGMAC1R7Cz5BEQBvYCwQAG0ABWAuYABrVER6GwQAXRUDUkoaBhZFbj4yxv5jEABfE1gcCFNQYABVdAsyVEnx0FHsYABBFJTUZDxgek4fRARCOTw0iz2LzyJnZEZ6eIJgFN8fVGlgACJ7x6%20XC5XCxyZzefxEVxEerybpkLA2PycFJ4dgHFwYPB8ACMYgkUlkwAKv2QBgUHG4wCG-AAFABKQlFQogEApA4KYBUAzwLHFH4PZBfRrCb5kpRfQxrABywQojAejGA1IA7kwqkonHJNKhkR96Yz9cyXmy9oguTy%20X8hSIAAwSuCy%20WKlWMNUU4HATQ66S0xlmJJuTh%20ewAI1QjDcFTknHoe2B6HYZE4FmD7yCLn98F5xMFbgAdL6pkg0MAA0HQ%20HI8Bo7H0PHE8nU3hgpCS6KKbo2po8wbmYz3nt7PQlQZUhkstjcoShoNmYOlbnicK3JIFG47VMHUwuWl2HIDkRdwCiIjxGgvftOEQAJIArhVeRpeh%20HyfUPAZ2usj5w1jE7FjywhGh7VhqdZJimELNv6nYdEwrDkrwmYWgK-TdsMUBAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear the first misconception here.

> T['prop']'s type can be inferred at this point to be identical to string (we see this working on const x and y the function)

You are forgetting about *literal types*.

```
function test<T extends { prop: string }>() {
  const x: T["prop"] = "string";
}

test<{ prop: "a" | "b" }>()
```

`prop` is only constrained to *extend* `string`. But the caller could also specify literal type or a union of such. The assignment of `"string"` to a variable of type `T["prop"]` could be unsound if `prop` is typed as `"a" | "b"`.

So why does this assignment work then? The TypeScript team has decided *eagerly* anaylize generic types by their constraint when a property type is accessed. The type of `T["prop"]` is *widened* to the `string` type which makes working with it *as if it were a `string`* possible.

The alternative would be to leave the type as `T["prop"]`. But *nothing* would be assignable to this type *except* `T["prop"]` which would make it not useful in most situations.

So you are seeing a situation where the compiler is more *leniant* than it should be leading to possible unsound situations.

---

The problem with the assignability of `"test"` to `mow.prop` has a different cause though.

```
function test<T extends { prop: string }>() {
  let mow: Schema<T> = {};
  mow.prop = "test"; 
}
```

`Schema<T>` contains a *mapped type* where the property types are computed with a *conditional*. But fully computing the result of `Schema<T>` is impossible as `T` is a generic type which is specified by the caller of the function. We can see that the *constraint* of `T` is used to approximate the result of the mapped type. But the compiler leaves the conditional untouched. The property types of `Schema<T>` remain essentially opaque as the compiler defers the evaluation of the conditional.

It seems to be sound to human logic that the conditional would resolve to `RegExp | T` for all `string` type properties. But the compiler does not try to reason about this whenever a conditional type depends on a generic type. You can find similar problems with conditionals at [#28884](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884) or [#43846](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43846).

Comment: Thank you for the helpful information, good to know the limitations of the compiler and why. Would you happen to have a suggestion of how to accomplish something like this then. In my particular case I can't change the types (they are from a third party library, can add new ones composed of them though). So the goal is to limit this function to objects with a specific property (like `prop`) so I can set its value in the function.

Comment: Does the function *have* to be generic? Right now, it does not look like the return type/parameter types depend on each other. If it has to be generic, just use a type assertion when assigning values.